Love makes a woman (more) beautiful

(1) Love makes a woman beautiful.
(2) Love makes a woman more beautiful.

Which sentence sounds idiomatic?
(1) is my word-for-word English translation of a commonly used Japanese expression, but I don't know whether it sounds natural in English.
I think (2) might be better because a Japanese teacher of English corrected my sentence "She'll get well soon" to "She'll get better soon". (I still don't know why "She'll get well soon" is unnatural.)
[Edit] In Japan, the original Japanese expression is not sexist at all. There are many blog posts written by Japanese women in which that expression is being used.

In English-speaking countries, 'Get well soon' is the normal thing to say to people who are sick, and you can buy pre-printed cards to send to them called 'Get well soon cards', or 'Get Well cards'. You can tell your teacher this. A link to some cards https://www.etsy.com/uk/c/paper-and-party-supplies/paper/greeting-cards/get-well-cards

It is often said that women who are expecting a baby, glow with health. You might say that a young person (or why not old) glows when they have fallen in love.

Hatred makes a man ugly.

@MichaelHarvey Is "I hope you'll get well soon" a normal thing to say?

Saying "I hope you get well soon" is a very normal thing to say.  Do a Google search.

"I hope you get well soon" is the normal conventional thing to say, which is why it appears on cards that you can buy.

Thank you, Michael Harvey. Is Google search reliable? It seems that the web is infested with English by non-native speakers of English. I have several occasions when I created a sentence using an expression I found by Google search and had native English speakers check it, only to be told that that sentence sounded unnatural.

@TimR - in Britain, some people talk of 'beer goggles' which are said to enhance people's appearances.

In either case, these sentences are a little bit ambiguous - does a woman actually become objectively more attractive when she is in love; or does she appear to be more attractive to the person who loves her?  Which meaning does the original Japanese expression have?

@MichaelHarvey  Judgement of beauty can err, what with the wine and the dark. -- Ovid

@CanadianYankee Neither. I am far from an advanced learner of English, so I cannot expound on how the expression is used in Japan. But I  can give a typical example of it. For example, "It's not a myth that love makes a woman beautiful. In fact, since I fell in love, my skin has become clearer and my hair has become lustrous."

Surely any kind of increased happiness, and not just 'love', would increase bodily health?

Both are idiomatic, but have very different meanings.

Love makes a woman beautiful.

This means that a woman becomes beautiful under the influence of love, regardless of how attractive or unattractive she is otherwise.

Love makes a woman more beautiful.

This means that a woman becomes more beautiful under the influence of love than she is otherwise: a beautiful woman becomes even more beautiful, however an unattractive woman maybe only becomes less unattractive.
Note that neither sentence makes it clear whether somebody loving the woman, or the woman loving somebody, produces this effect.

It could also mean than if you 'love' a woman, she becomes beautiful, or more beautiful,  in your eyes. Also applies to pets, children, etc. On a personal note, I find the original sentences a bit sexist.

@MichaelHarvey While I too feel uneasy with the sentences, there is no doubt some truth in them. When a woman finds a man attractive, her pupils dilate and her lips redden: both of these changes make her seem more attractive- hence women wear lipstick and used to put belladonna in their eyes.  It's more difficult to demonstrate objectively but, a you say, a woman probably seems more attractive to a man who  loves her.

@MichaelHarvey In Japan, the original Japanese sentence, a commonly used set expression, is not sexist at all.

@JavaLatte In Japan, the original Japanese sentence, a commonly used set expression, is normally about a woman who loves a man.

Neither sentence is particularly idiomatic, but both are perfectly good English and could be something said by a native speaker. My only suggestion is that, if you are aiming at an accurate translation then does the word more appear in the original? Alternatively, if you are going for a more free translation you should consider the wider context. For example, in a romantic passage then, in my opinion, include more.
The difference between getting well and getting better is a bit subtle.
Well is a state of being. "I am well" can mean "I am fit and healthy".
Getting better is the action or process of recovery from illness or injury.
So you should say "She will be well soon"
However typical greetings to a sick person in the UK might be either "Get better soon" or "Get well soon" both of which are wishes for a full recovery.

Thank you, Peter Jennings. The original Japanese sentence, a commonly used set expression, does not have the word "more".

Now I know "I hope you'll get better soon" is misleadingly translated into Japanese in a popular English-Japanese dictionary. I am fully satisfied with your answer. Thank you very much, Peter Jennings.
